# BAD SUBSTITUTION: String comparison using array elements in bash

Tags: bash

I'm getting started with bash programming, and am stumbling through the syntax a little. The following is part of the code to play tic-tac-toe from the command line.

```
i=0
initialGrid=('_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_')
if [ "${ initialGrid[ $i ] }" = "_" ]; then
echo "I'm here"
fi
```

However I get the following error

```
tic.sh: line 48: ${ initialGrid[ $i ] }: bad substituion
```

So the echo never gets executed

I was able to substitute the above if statement and do the following without error

```
element=" $initialGrid[$i] "
if [ "${!element}" = "_" ]; then
echo "Element equals underscore"
fi
```

But again, the echo never gets execute even though i believe it clearly should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces in bash almost always are special characters. In your first case:

```
i=0
initialGrid=('_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_')
if [ "${ initialGrid[ $i ] }" = "_" ]; then
  echo "I'm here"
fi
```

You need to replace the line with the condition with

```
if [ "${initialGrid[$i]}" = "_" ]; then
```

In your second case, you are padding the value with spaces, but then trying to compare it to the value without spaces, `_` is not the same as `_`. You are also not dereferencing the array correctly.

```
element=" $initialGrid[$i] "
if [ "${!element}" = "_" ]; then
  echo "Element equals underscore"
fi
```

Replace the first line with `element="${initialGrid[$i]}"`

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are not optional. You need to use:

```
if [[ "${initialGrid[i]}" == "_" ]]; then echo "I'm here"; fi
```